I know I can create folders from a list.txt, but can I move files to those folders based on a mapping?
If right now, I only had a bunch of files dumped into a single directory, is there a way that I could move the files into a folder based on a mapping file.  For example:




A
B




1
File Name
Folder Name


2
abc
123


3
def
456


4
ghi
789


5
jkl
123


6
mno
456



is it possible to move file abc and jkl to folder 123 based on this mapping?  I'm not familiar with coding; I really just want to know if it's doable.
Thanks in advance!

I replaced the tags [tag:windows] and [tag:sqlserver] with tags that I thought fit the question better. If you want to add your original tags, then you may want to explain how they are relevant.

Nicole, do you realise that by asking here you won't get a Windows-centric answer?

You could export the file, exclusive of the header, to a tab-delimited CSV (let's call it "pairs" - the CSV shall not be exported double-quoting or otherwise delimiting text fields - see the caveats below) and then run this in Bash:
while IFS=$'\t' read src dst; do mv -n -- "$src" "$dst/"; done <pairs

(thanks to @steeldriver for improving on my original answer)
If you also want it to create the destination directory if it doesn't exist (warning: this will allow typos in the destination directory to go through unnoticed):
while IFS=$'\t' read src dst; do mkdir -p "$dst" && mv -n -- "$src" "$dst/"; done <pairs

(thanks to @EdMorton for suggesting this option)

while IFS=$'\t' read src dst; do [...]; done <pairs: will set the shell's internal field separator to a tab character while executing read, which will read from "pairs" one line at the time, splitting the line's contents on tab characters and into two variables (src and dest) at each iteration
mv -n -- "$src" "$dst/": will run mv on src and dest, avoiding overwriting existing files

$ cat pairs 
baz     foo/bar
$ tree -ap .
[drwxrwxr-x]  .
├── [-rw-rw-r--]  baz
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  foo
│   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  bar
└── [-rw-rw-r--]  pairs

3 directories, 2 files
$ while IFS=$'\t' read src dst; do mv -n -- "$src" "$dst/"; done <pairs
$ tree -ap .
[drwxrwxr-x]  .
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  foo
│   └── [drwxrwxr-x]  bar
│       └── [-rw-rw-r--]  baz
└── [-rw-rw-r--]  pairs

3 directories, 2 files

There are advantages to using this method, such as the lack of need to escape characters normally included in IFS (besides tabs - you should escape tabs) and the lack of need to escape shell metacharacters when creating the file;
But there are also limitations, such as: source and destination paths / filenames won't undergo tilde expansion, so you won't be able to refer to /home/<your_username> using ~.
Also, no support for source and destination paths / filenames containing newlines.

Hopefully I got it right this time, if someone spots some pitfalls other than those I already mentioned in my answer I'd appreciate them commenting and letting me know.

In bash, wouldn't while IFS=$'\t' read -r src dst; do mv -n -- "$src" "$dst/"; done <pairs be more idiomatic? It doesn't require a subshell, and the quotes protect from globbing as well as word splitting.

@steeldriver You're right, that also makes it possible to go around the inability to list paths / filenames containing tabs (removing the -r option from read... Unless I'm missing something again), thank you, I've changed my answer accordingly

Maybe worth noting that if file/directory names contain tabs or backslash characters, they must be escaped with backslash.

Can't see why it wouldn't work in zsh or any shell supporting the ksh93-style $'...' quotes. mv -n is not standard though.

@kos afaik omitting the -r doesn't help dealing with actual tabs, but will make read interpret escape sequences like \t as plain t

@StéphaneChazelas "such as the lack of need to escape characters normally included in IFS (besides tabs)" - I was implying that with this statement, however perhaps it wasn't explicit enough, so I bolded a "you should escape tabs" statement as well; and you're right that this will indeed work in Zsh, that snippet - which I forgot to remove from the answer with the last edit - I had in my answer cause my previous method was doing things differently, and wouldn't work in Zsh. Thank you

@steeldriver Yeah that's the idea, if by removing -r we're allowing "" to escape characters such as tabs which, otherwise, would be split by read, then we can also use those characters, properly escaped, in paths / filenames listed in the CSV, am I misunderstanding something?

@kos fair enough - I guess we can't say which is more appropriate without knowing exactly how the OP's "mapping file" is formatted

Thanks all!  posting to this forum was out of desperation.  Based on the responses, it sounds 100% doable.  Now I just have to go find the right person who knows what they are doing.  Appreciate all your time!

You might want to add a mkdir -p "$dst" && before trying to move a file into "$dst" to make sure it exists.

@EdMorton Good point in general, however I don't think that behavior would be desirable in this case; it might be more desirable for the script to error out in case the destination doesn't exist, otherwise typos in the destination path (much more likely to happen when compiling a spreadsheet than when typing in a shell with tab completion) would go unnoticed and files would be moved to an unwanted directory.

Ture, we just can't tell from the question what the OP wants.

@EdMorton Added another version of the command incorporating your suggestion, with a bolded caveat, so that everyone (OP and future visitors, if they desire such behavior) is happy, thanks for the suggestion

If the list is in a CSV file, for example:
$ cat file.csv
"FileName","FolderName"
"A file","/path/to/some directory"
"Another file, with comma and ""quotes""","/some/other
directory with newlines"

You could process it with:
perl -MFile::Copy -MText::CSV=csv -e '
  for (@{csv(in => shift, binary => 1, headers => "auto")}) {
    move $_->{FileName}, "$_->{FolderName}/" or
      die "Cannot move $_->{FileName}: $!\n"
  }' -- file.csv

To also create the target directories if they don't exist:
perl -MFile::Copy -MFile::Path=make_path -MText::CSV=csv -e '
  for (@{csv(in => shift, binary => 1, headers => "auto")}) {
    make_path $_->{FolderName};
    move $_->{FileName}, "$_->{FolderName}/" or
      die "Cannot move $_->{FileName}: $!\n";
  }' -- file.csv


Yes, assuming that the file pairs is blank-separated, and none of the file/directory names contain blank characters, you could do:
sed -n "s/^\([^[:blank:]']\+\)[[:blank:]]\+\([^[:blank:]']\+\)\$/mv -- '\1' '\2'/p" | sh


Also assumes the file names don't contain apostrophe characters (or otherwise you have an ACE vulnerability). Also assumes GNU sed or compatible for the \+. See \{1,\} for the standard equivalent.
